# .Net core 2.0 Angular template - webpack converts the templateUrl to template

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I've opened a new .net core 2.0 Angular application just for fun, and immediately I've noticed that the angular metadata attribute is converted from *templateUrl* to *template* after the minification.

I believe that this is happening because of the server-side prerendering, but I don't what to use *.html* files since this is a .net core application where I can use *.cshtml*

What happens:

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: 'home/news' // <-- Here I want to load a razor page, 
                             // from homecontroller/news.cshtml
})
export class HomeComponent {
}
```

**main-client.js**

```
var HomeComponent = (function () {
    function HomeComponent() {
    }
    HomeComponent = __decorate([
        __webpack_require__.i(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__["Component"])({
            selector: 'home',
            template: __webpack_require__(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \"./home/news\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()))
        })
    ], HomeComponent);
    return HomeComponent;
}());
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js', '.ts' ] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader', 'angular2-router-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot.browser.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new AotPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.browser.module#AppModule'),
                exclude: ['./**/*.server.ts']
            })
        ])
    });

    // Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot.server.ts' },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./ClientApp/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
                sourceType: 'commonjs2',
                name: './vendor'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new AotPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.server.module#AppModule'),
                exclude: ['./**/*.browser.ts']
            })
        ]),
        output: {
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
        },
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
};
```

I don't have any experience with *webpack*, I am used to gulp/grunt, and I don't know how to configure the *webpack* for this particular case.

Comment: the razor page exists only on the server side (even if it is precompiled) so in order to use it as a template for angular component you would have to retrieve it from the server via http call for example. Anyway you should not mix it this way. View logic should be written in typescript, and if you need some data from back-end - the best way would be http call to rest api provided by asp.net.

Comment: Found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476792/how-to-compile-angular-2-webpack-by-keeping-templateurl-as-is